# Concatenating selected strings in list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, tuples

The problem is as follows. I have a list of strings

```
lst1=['puffing','his','first','cigarette','in', 'weeks', 'in', 'weeks']
```

and I would like to obtain the string

```
lst2=['puffing','his','first','cigarette','in weeks', 'in weeks']
```

that is to concatenate any occurence of the sublist `['in', 'weeks']` for reasons that are irrelevant here, where `find_sub_list1` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870544/find-starting-and-ending-indices-of-sublist-in-list) (and included in the code below):

```
npis = [['in', 'weeks'], ['in', 'ages']]

# given a list a candidate sublist, return the index of the first and last
# element of the sublist within the list
def find_sub_list1(sl,l):
    results=[]
    sll=len(sl)
    for ind in (i for i,e in enumerate(l) if e==sl[0]):
        if l[ind:ind+sll]==sl:
        results.append((ind,ind+sll-1))

    return results

def concatenator(sent, npis):
    indices = []
    for npi in npis:
        indices_temp = find_sub_list1(npi, sent)
        if indices_temp != []:
            indices.extend(indices_temp)
    sorted(indices, key=lambda x: x[0])

    for (a,b) in indices:
        diff = b - a
        sent[a:b+1] = [" ".join(sent[a:b+1])]
        del indices[0]
        indices = [(a - diff, b - diff) for (a,b) in indices]

    return sent
```

instead of the desired `lst2` this coder returns:

```
concatenator(lst1,['in', 'weeks'])
>>['puffing','his','first','cigarette','in weeks', 'in', 'weeks']
```

so it only concatenates the first occurrence. Any ideas about where the code is failing?

Comment: a better way to concatenate the two words would be to work backwards. that way you wont have to adjust the remaining indices with the `diff`

Comment: How did I miss that! Great suggestion! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

since the desired sub-sequence is `'in' 'weeks'` *and possibly `'in''ages'`*

One possible solution could be (the looping is not very elegant though):

1. first find all positions where `'in'` occurs.
2. then iterate through the source list, appending elements to the target list, and treating the positions of `'in'` specially, i.e. if the following word is in a special set then join the two & append to the target, advancing the iterator one extra time.
3. Once the source list is exhausted an IndexError will be thrown, indicating that we should break the loop.

code:

```
index_in = [i for i, _ in enumerate(lst1) if _ == 'in']

lst2 = []; n = 0

while True:
    try:
         if n in index_in and lst1[n+1] in ['weeks', 'ages']:
             lst2.append(lst1[n] + lst1[n+1])
             n += 1
         else:
             lst2.append(lst1[n])
         n += 1
     except IndexError:
         break
```

A better way to do this would be through regular expressions.

1. join the list to a string with space as a separator
2. split the list on spaces, except those spaces surrounded by `in<space>weeks`. Here, we can use negative lookahead & lookbehind

code:

```
import re

c = re.compile(r'(?<!in) (?!weeks)')

lst2 = c.split(' '.join(lst1))
```

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a fix for your code, but an alternate solution (I always end up using regex for everything)

```
import re
list1_str = ','.join(lst1)
npis_concat = [','.join(x) for x in npis]
for item in npis_concat:
    list1_str = re.sub(r'\b'+item+r'\b',item.replace(',', ' '),list1_str)
lst1 = list1_str.split(',')
```

I use a comma here, but you can replace it with any character, preferably one you know wont be in your text

the `r'\b'` are used to make sure we don't accidentally chop of bits from words ending/beginning with stuff in npis