# Python: Extracting lists from list with module or regular expression

Tags: python, regex, list, search

I'm trying to extract lists/sublists from one bigger integer-list with Python2.7 by using start- and end-patterns. I would like to do it with a function, but I cant find a library, algorithm or a regular expression for solving this problem.

```
def myFunctionForSublists(data, startSequence, endSequence):
    # ... todo

data = [99, 99, 1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6, 99, 99, 1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 5, 6, 99]

startSequence = [1,2,3]
endSequence = [4,5,6]

sublists = myFunctionForSublists(data, startSequence, endSequence)

print sublists[0] # [1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6]
print sublists[1] # [1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 5, 6]
```

Any ideas how I can realize it?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: @Prateek his expected output is shown by what he expects the print statements to print

Comment: what is startSequence? does it mean similar to startswith ?

Comment: If you want to do it using regex, you need to use String and can't be applied on Integer list. If you want to apply it on String, you can do it like this https://regex101.com/r/l1sx9V/1/

Comment: Can sublists overlap?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more general solution that doesn't require the lists being sliceable, so you can use it on other iterables, like generators.

We keep a `deque` the size of the `start` sequence until we come across it.  Then we add those values to a list, and keep iterating over the sequence.  As we do, we keep a `deque` the size of the end sequence, until we see it, also adding the elements to the list we're keeping.  If we come across the end sequence, we `yield` that list and set the `deque` up to scan for the next start sequence.

```
from collections import deque

def gen(l, start, stop):
    start_deque = deque(start)
    end_deque = deque(stop)
    curr_deque = deque(maxlen=len(start))
    it = iter(l)
    for c in it:
        curr_deque.append(c)
        if curr_deque == start_deque:
            potential = list(curr_deque)
            curr_deque = deque(maxlen=len(stop))
            for c in it:
                potential.append(c)
                curr_deque.append(c)
                if curr_deque == end_deque:
                    yield potential
                    curr_deque = deque(maxlen=len(start))
                    break

print(list(gen([99, 99, 1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6, 99, 99, 1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 5, 6, 99], [1,2,3], [4,5,6])))

# [[1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: It seems like we had the same idea, but managed to have sufficiently different looking implementations!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an itertools approach that uses a `collections.deque` of limited length to keep a buffer of the last elements of appropriate size. It assumes that your sublists don't overlap and that your start and end sequences don't overlap either.

It works for any sequence for data, start, end (even generators).

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

def sublists(data, start, end):
    it = iter(data)
    start, end = deque(start), deque(end)
    while True:
        x = deque(islice(it, len(start)), len(start))
        # move forward until start is found
        while x != start:
            x.append(next(it))
        out = list(x)
        x = deque(islice(it, len(end)), len(end))
        # move forward until end is found, storing the sublist
        while x != end:
            out.append(x[0])
            x.append(next(it))
        out.extend(end)
        yield out

data = [99, 99, 1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6, 99, 99, 1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 5, 6, 99]

startSequence = [1,2,3]
endSequence = [4,5,6]

print(list(sublists(data, startSequence, endSequence)))
# [[1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regular expressions, you can change the lists of integers to strings and use the regex that way

```
import re

def find_span(numbers, start, end):
    # Create strings from the start and end lists.
    start_pattern = ''.join(map(chr, start))
    end_pattern = ''.join(map(chr, end))

    # convert the list to search into one string.
    s = ''.join(map(chr, numbers))

    # Create a pattern that starts and ends with the correct sublists,
    # and match all sublists. Then convert each match back to a list of
    # integers
    # The '?' is to make the regex non-greedy
    return [
        [ord(c) for c in match]
        for match in re.findall(rf'{start_pattern}.*?{end_pattern}', s, re.DOTALL)
    ]

>>> find_span(search, start, end)  # Using OP's sample values
[[1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Note this is not really efficient, since it requires dynamically building a regex each time it's called. And you need to use `re.DOTALL` because otherwise it won't match anything containing `10` (which is the ascii encoding of newline). However, if you ***really want to use regexes***, this would work.

Comment: firstly use map to convert int to str. Are you sure it is giving the expected result as posted by OP? I was trying regex but can't get rid of some of the overlappings

Comment: @mad_ Thanks. I realized I forgot the `?` which makes the regex non-greedy. It does give the output OP wanted with that change.

Comment: can you please post the output as well? Just want to know what I am doing wrong. Would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @mad_ updated the output. `int` needs to be replaced with `ord` as well (forgot to copy that change when I updated the non-greedy symbol)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate all in indices in the list and compare the slice to the `startSequence` or the `endSequence`, respectively. Assuming that the sublists are not supposed to overlap, you can use the same iterator for both loops.

```
def myFunctionForSublists(data, startSequence, endSequence):
    positions = iter(range(len(data)))
    for start in positions:
        if data[start:start+len(startSequence)] == startSequence:
            for end in positions:
                if data[end:end+len(endSequence)] == endSequence:
                    yield data[start:end+len(endSequence)]
                    break
```

This way, the `start` loop will continue where the `end` loop left. If they *can* overlap, use two separate iterators for the loop, i.e. `for start in range(len(data)):` and  `for end in range(start+1, len(data)):`

Answer (score 0):

Use below method:

```
def find_sub_list(sl,l):
    sll=len(sl)
    for ind in (i for i,e in enumerate(l) if e==sl[0]):
        if l[ind:ind+sll]==sl:
            return ind,ind+sll-1

find_sub_list([1,2,3], data)    
>>>(2, 4)
find_sub_list([4,5,6], data)    
>>>(8, 10)

data[2:10+1]
>>>[1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6]
```

You can follow similar approach for `sublists[1]`

Courtesy : [find-starting-and-ending-indices-of-sublist-in-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870544/find-starting-and-ending-indices-of-sublist-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a O(n) solution that finds matches by keeping track of matching patterns of startSequence and endSequence

```
def myFunctionForSublists(data, startSequence, endSequence):
    start,end = tuple(startSequence), tuple(endSequence)
    l1, l2    = len(start), len(end)
    s = -1
    result = []
    for i,v in enumerate(zip(*[data[i:] for i in range(0,l1)])):
        if v == start:
            s = i
        if v == end and s != -1:
            result.append(data[s:i+l2])
            s = -1

    return result


print (myFunctionForSublists(data, startSequence, endSequence))
# [[1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 5, 6]]
```