# Find the specific sequence of words in list

Tags: python

I need to find the starting index of the specific sequences (sequence of strings)  in the list in python.

For ex.

```
list = ['In', 'a', 'gesture', 'sure', 'to', 'rattle', 'the', 'Chinese', 'Government', ',', 'Steven', 'Spielberg', 'pulled', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'Beijing', 'Olympics', 'to', 'protest', 'against', 'China', '_s', 'backing', 'for', 'Sudan', '_s', 'policy', 'in', 'Darfur', '.']
```

ex.

```
seq0 = "Steven Spielberg"
seq1 = "the Chinese Government"
seq2 = "the Beijing Olympics"
```

The output should be like :

```
10
6
15
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Find starting and ending indices of sublist in list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17870544/1324033)

Comment: Thank you @Sayse .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply iterate over list of your words and check at every index if following words match any of your sequences.

```
words = ['In', 'a', 'gesture', 'sure', 'to', 'rattle', 'the', 'Chinese', 'Government', ',', 'Steven', 'Spielberg', 'pulled', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'Beijing', 'Olympics', 'to', 'protest', 'against', 'China', '_s', 'backing', 'for', 'Sudan', '_s', 'policy', 'in', 'Darfur', '.']\

seq0 = "Steven Spielberg"
seq1 = "the Chinese Government"
seq2 = "the Beijing Olympics"

sequences = {'seq{}'.format(idx): i.split() for idx, i in enumerate([seq0, seq1, seq2])}

for idx in range(len(words)):
    for k, v in sequences.items():
        if idx + len(v) < len(words) and words[idx: idx+len(v)] == v:
            print(k, idx)
```

**Output:**

```
seq1 6
seq0 10
seq2 15
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like:**

```
def find_sequence(seq, _list):
    seq_list = seq.split()
    all_occurrence = [idx for idx in [i for i, x in enumerate(_list) if x == seq_list[0]] if seq_list == list_[idx:idx+len(seq_list)]]
    return -1 if not all_occurrence else all_occurrence[0]
```

---

**Output:**

```
for seq in [seq0, seq1, seq2]:
    print(find_sequence(seq, list_))
```

> 10
>
> 6
>
> 15

**Note**, if the sequence is not found you will get **-1**.